# Android SQLite INSERT OR IGNORE doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

Why do the IGNORE statement doesn't work? Everytime I run this the same value were insert in the database and I don't know why?

```
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDB.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + MY_DB_TABLE + "(db_datum, db_zahlen, db_scheine)" 
                +"VALUES ('"+datum+"',"+
                "'"+zahlen+"',"+
                "'"+9+"');");
```

db schema is:

- db_datum (varchar(100))
- db_zahlen (varchar(100))
- db_scheine (integer)

I have the 2 String "datum" and "zahlen" and would like to insert them in the database. Now the problem is, if the same strings are already in the db and the code run again they sould be ignored and never insert again.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what is happening without the table/db schema. Can you add them to your question?

Comment: Could you be more specific. What do you expect to go into the database and what do you get. Overall it sounds like you the IGNORE statement does not do what you think it does. IGNORE ignores constraint errors, so if you get the same value with the same primary key, that's no wonder.

Comment: I have add the schema and some information.

Comment: Ok. If none of those of those fields have the "UNIQUE" constraint, or are primary keys, then you would be able to insert those values as often as you wish. So if you don't have the constraints you should be getting the behavior you are getting.

Answer (score 17):

You can use insertWithOnConflict. 
Ex:

```
mDb.insertWithOnConflict(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Comment: According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), min API 15 should be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `execSQL` to do an INSERT command (check the docs).

Use `myDB.insertOrThrow(...)` instead :

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("db_datum", datum);
cv.put("db_zahlen", zahlen);
cv.put("db_scheine", 9);
myDB.insertOrThrow(MY_DB_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Comment: Well, that might be too slow. It an often be faster to create 1 sql statement containing multiple values at once.